# Wordpress: Combination of Page id and Category id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on an old wordpress site (3.6), I have imported all the posts succesfully, I'm trying to replicate some page which have urls which are combination of page id and category id, example:

http://localhost/?page_id=17&cat_id=3

I know there are ids for pages and categories but I'm not quite sure what their combination means and how to replicate it, I've tried to use the same url for the new site but it does not work. I've tried googling for a solution but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means display all posts on page with id 17 from category 3. The reason you are not able to find anything with the old URL on the new site is because the URL structure might be different from the old site.